# Python CSV to Excel sheet by sheet with openpyxl [NOT OPTIMIZED]

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I actually have a program who read a csv and insert it in a xlsx sheet, but actually this program take too much time to execute and i don't know how i can't optimize it, if you have some tips help me please.

````
    df = pd.read_csv( file, sep=';', decimal='.', encoding="utf-8", index_col=False )
    df.to_excel( 'tmp.xlsx', sheet_name=action, index=None, header=True )

    book = openpyxl.load_workbook( template_file )
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter( template_file, engine='openpyxl' )
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict( ( ws.title, ws ) for ws in book.worksheets )
    df.to_excel( writer, action, index=None )
    writer.save()
    os.remove( 'tmp.xlsx' )```
````

Comment: By using a template file, you're forcing openpyxl to load everything into memory. Things will be a lot faster if you can avoid this and Pandas as well, which you also don't seem to need.

Comment: Actually i have 8 csv files who need to be loaded into xlsx but each csv file go into a special sheet of the xlsx, i don't know how i can't make it without those tmp files

Comment: Just chain the csv rows with openpyxl rows in read-only mode.

Comment: i don't understand how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an Excel spreadsheet with 8 different sheets (one per CSV file) you could use the following approach:

```
import openpyxl
import csv
import os

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
del wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]        # Remove the default 'Sheet1'

for filename in ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']:
    with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
        ws = wb.create_sheet(title=os.path.basename(filename))
        
        for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';'):
            ws.append(row)
        
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

1. First create an Excel workbook to store you CSV data in (and remove the default sheet).
2. For each file create a new worksheet. Give the sheet the same name as the filename (assumes the filenames are not too long).
3. For each row in the CSV file, use `ws.append()` to write the row into the worksheet.
4. When all files are processed, write the whole Excel spreadsheet out.

---

If you have an existing Excel spreadsheet to update, the following approach could be used:

```
import openpyxl
import csv
import os

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')

sheets = [
    ('file1.csv', 'Sheet A'),
    ('file2.csv', 'Sheet B'),
    ('file3.csv', 'Sheet C')
]

for filename, sheet in sheets:
    with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
        ws = wb[sheet]
        
        for rowy, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';'), start=1):    # make start first row number
            for colx, value in enumerate(row, start=1):                             # make start first col number    
                ws.cell(column=colx, row=rowy, value=value)
        
wb.save('data.xlsx')
```

This first reads the existing template file in an overwrites the existing entries (starting top left at 'A1')

Comment: Thanks ! I don't need to create worksheet because i'm using a template file who already got everything but now i load this template and save it only one time instead of every worksheet loop

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed you were updating an existing spreadsheet. I've added an updated solution to help with that too